# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 4 String replaceAll()

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "ABC KK {PASSWORD}";
    String b = "Pass$491";

    String x = a.replaceAll("\\{PASSWORD}", b);
    System.out.println("======" + x);

}
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 4
at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.start(Matcher.java:482)
at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.appendExpandedReplacement(Matcher.java:1090)
at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:997)
at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceAll(Matcher.java:1181)
at java.base/java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2939)

Comment: Hint: read the documentation for `String.replaceAll`, and then the documentation for `Matcher.replaceAll`. I suspect you'd actually be better off with `String.replace` and avoid the regexes...

Answer (score 0):

`replaceAll` is a misnomer. `replace` and `replaceAll` **both** replace *all* instances of the thing you're looking for. However, `replaceAll` treats its first argument as a *regular expression* and the second as a regular expression replacement string. Whereas `replace` just treats both args as plain strings.

Thus, to fix this, either escape that `$4`, which is regexpese for 'replace it with the 4th matching group', or more likely, use replace:

```
a.replace("{PASSWORD}", b);
```

Did you just paste a password in a stackoverflow question? You... might wanna change it now.

Answer (score 0):

My solution

```
    String a = "ABC KK {PASSWORD}";
    String b = "Pass$491";
    String x = a.replaceAll("\\{PASSWORD}", Matcher.quoteReplacement(b));
```

By passing the string in `Mather.quotereplacement()` will remove the special meaning of $ sign in regex expression and replaceall consider it as a normal string and this resolves my issue